# How to I add the IIS pool identity of my App Service local groups such as Performance Monitor Users

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, application-pool

I am current working out how to host and existing APS.NET application in Azure but it needs to access registry keys in order to register performance counters.
I have not come across a way to do this without needing elevated access.
If I try to use the command line tools I get access denied.
e.g. If I try to use commands like

```cs
net localgroup "performance monitor users" IIS APPPOOL\MyServiceAppPool /add
```

Comment: you won't have this priviledge using app services (web sites).

Comment: If you are hosting the web app on Azure App Service, you should consider the underlying OS is locked down and you shouldn't try to read things like registry keys. Performance of your web app should be queried using the recommended approaches, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps

Comment: thanks. was not the answer i was looking for but was the answer i suspected. Will do thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use Windows Containers on App Service in which you have full control.

Here you can follow the quickstart to run a Windows Container in App Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container